# urldecode a list in Python

Tags: python, urllib, urldecode

I'm a noobie and I've been struggling on this simple code for too long, so i thought i'd ask for help.

I'm attempting to open a CSV and decode the URL text e.g. `example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0` and then save the file. I can do this easily with a string, but i'm struggling to do it with rows in a CSV.

My attempt so far:

```
#reading
file1 = open('example.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file1)
url = []
for rows in reader:
    url.append = urllib.unquote(rows).decode('utf8')
    #also tried "url.append(urllib.unquote(rows).decode('utf8'))", but same error
file1.close() 

#writing
file2 = open('example.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(file2)
writer.writerows(url)
file2.close()
```

edit:
The error i'm receiving..

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Find a good example if how to use `append`. You are using it wrongly.

Comment: url.append(urllib.unquote(rows).decode('utf8'))?

Comment: sorry the error i'm receiving is AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I also tried the above solution but still the same error. I have edited the original post to reflect the above

Comment: By the way, you seem to only have a "single column" in your CSV file, i.e. one URL per line. That's not CSV, that's a plain old regular text file.

Comment: Paste an example of your `csv` file.. your question is not making any sense

Comment: Tomalak is correct, it's just one URL line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your approach.

1. You don't seem to have CSV, but a regular text file with one value per line. There is no benefit in using the `csv` module here, Python can read text files just fine. In fact, "line-wise" the default mode when you open a text file for reading.
2. When you read or write *any* text file, you **must** declare the encoding the text file is in when you `open()` it. Python has no magic text encoding detector, when you don't specify an encoding, reading the file properly may work on your machine and break on another, because different computer configurations may have different "default" encodings.
3. URLs are complex data structures, applying "urldecode" to them is not good enough. You need to *parse* them - luckily an URL parser is built into Python. The URL parser will give you a `ParseResult` object that conveniently exposes all the different parts of the URL as properties.
4. URLs consist of many parts, the query string is one of them.
5. Query strings are complex data structures, applying "urldecode" to them is not good enough. You need to *parse* them - luckily a query string parser is built into Python. The query string parser will automatically decode the values for you and give you a `dict` that you can access with keys.
6. `.append` is a function. You can't assign to it (`.append = '...'`), you need to call it (`.append('...')`).
7. Lastly, it's easier to use a `with` block to work with files, because `with` blocks close the file automatically.

Compare:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

with open('example.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    titles = []

    for url in file1:
        parts = urlparse(url)
        # -> ParseResult(
        #      scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='', params='',
        #      query='title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0',
        #      fragment='')

        q = parse_qs(parts.query)
        # -> {'title': ['правовая защита']}

        if 'title' in q:
            titles.append(q['title'][0])

    with open('titles.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file2:
        file2.writelines(titles)
```

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and dropping the unnecessary comments, we can compress the above code quite a bit:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

with open('example.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file1:
    queries = [parse_qs(urlparse(url).query) for url in file1]

with open('titles.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file2:
    titles = [q['title'][0] for q in queries if 'title' in q]
    file2.writelines(titles)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I can see where I went wrong!

Comment: Of course I made a few naming mistakes with my variables, I've corrected them now in my code.

Comment: Great answer! I think it should be `qs['title'][0]` though, `parse_qs` returns a dictionary of lists

Comment: @lemonhead That's a good point. I've added that and a shorter way to write it, too.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you might getting individual rows from the reader. I'm guessing these are probably available via index.

```
for row in reader
    url.append = urllib.unquote(row[0]).decode('utf8')
```

There is a also a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) in case list abstraction doesn't suffice.